# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"employee"' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-context

we are trying to convert existing JS code into TS but stuck in updating local state data. here apiData is expected to come from API due to which we dont know possibilities of fields.

DataContext.tsx

```
import { createContext,useContext, useState } from "react";


interface Data {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    apiData:object;    
  }

type DataContextType = {
    myData: Data;
    updateMyData: (myData: Data) => void;
  };

  
const DataContext = createContext<DataContextType | null>(null);

export const useDataContext =()=>{ return useContext(DataContext) as DataContextType};

export const DataContextProvider =({children}: any)=>{
    const [myData, setMyData]=useState<Data>({id:1,title:'this',apiData:{}})
    const updateMyData=(myData:Data)=>{
        setMyData(myData);
    }
    
    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={{myData,updateMyData}}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

page.tsx

```
"use client"

import { useEffect , useState} from 'react';
import {useDataContext} from '../context/DataContext' 

export default function Sample() { 
    const { myData,updateMyData } = useDataContext();
    const [name,setName]=useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(name.length===0)
        {
            updateMyData({id:2,title:'that',apiData:{employee:[{data:'tom'},{data:'harry'}]}});  
            setName(myData["apiData"]["employee"]);
        }      
    },[name]);
    
  return (
    <>
     
    <h1>hellow1</h1>
    {name.map((element)=>{ return <h2>{element.data}</h2>})}     
    </>
  )
}
```

TS Error

[image]

even tough updateMyData setting up employee data we are not able to setName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to make TS play along nicely.

`apiData: object` is not a well defined type. And hence you cannot use apiData["employee"]["data"], without TS screaming at you.
Replace that with:

```
apiData: { employee: { data: string }[] };
```

Even with that, you will get another error:

```
const [name, setName] = useState([]);
```

The way `setName` is defined it can only accept an empty tuple. This happens because React-Typescript narrows the type (of state variable) to the most specific one by its own. You should define the type of the state variable while calling `useState`.

Use the below to define the type:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<{ data: string }[]>([]);
```

[`useState`](https://www.robinwieruch.de/typescript-react-usestate/) is defined as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in typescript to facilitate using values of all types.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-tamas-forked-xwm5rg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A50%2C23). It is not functional but demos all the type errors and fixes.

Comment: apiData is going to come from API so it might change page to page. is there any way not define well for apiData and still suppressing TS errors

Comment: You could use `any` or `Record<string, any>`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is complaining about the fact that he doesn't know the type of `apiDate`, well he only knows that `apiData` is an `object` but nothing more.

You could simply update the type of `Data` to better define the shape of `apiData`, like this:

```js
interface Data {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  apiData: {
    employee: { data: string }[]
  };
}
```

But since you are fetching the data via API where you don't know all the fields I would recommend the use of [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod), in order to define a schema your data must validate to, and to infer the type of it:

```js
const apiSchema = z.object({
  employee: z.object({
    data: z.string()
  }).array()
})

interface Data {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  apiData: z.infer<typeof apiSchema>;
}

...

const response = await fetch("...");
const data = apiSchema.parse(await response.json());
```